# Character Enconding Problem in IBM DataStage Notification Activity

Tags: character-encoding, datastage

I'm having some trouble with DataStage notification activity when passing a text in PT-BR with accent as "Subject" in DSsendmail_template parameter and run a blat process. I'm using Blat cause my connection need authentication and DS default options doesn't allow It.

I've already tried to change Job NLS em properties, but had no effect.

Bellow the code in dssendmail_template.txt.

%body%

D:\ETL\BlatMail\Blat.exe  %file% -sf "%subject%" -f %from% -to "%to%" -server %server%

When running any Notification Activity mail is sent as expected, but subject is unreadeable.

Sending a test e-mail with subject "Envio de email por Blat Sem Autenticação" the result in blat execution is Subject:=?ISO-8859-1?Q?"=3D=3Futf-8=3FB=3FRW52aW8gZGUgZW1haWwgcG9yIEJsYXQgU2VtIEF1dGVudGljYcOnw6Nv=3F=3D"=20?=

There is any command a can run in windows command line to correct this problema or change DataStage configuration?

Comment: Did you try to send the mail using batch instead of Datastage ?

Comment: Yes, It works fine. But need many specific batchs or parameters for each job. The problem is we already have a good number of notification activities in our project working and cause of a infrasctrute change in mail server, we need to change for a Blat approach.